# Random Number Generator With alerts

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers

I'm attempting to make a program that generates a random number between 1 and 20 where if the number generated is less than 10 it alerts the word "fail" and if its more than 10 alerts the word "success". I cannot figure out where I went wrong. HELP!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 20.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Roll</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}    
    if (x < 10) 
{
    text = (x + “Success”);
}
    else 
{
    text = (x + “Fail”);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: Try replacing `“` & `”` by `'` or `"`

Comment: declare x outside of the function also `if the number generated is less than 10 it alerts the word "fail"` but your code will alert "Success" .you have to swap Success and fail

Comment: `x` exists ONLY in your function, and therefore is an undefined variable when you do the `if()` test - check your JS debug console to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote the quotes in a wrong way `""` and you have scopes issues see the [codepen snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOOMPN) and figure out your mistakes

```
var x='';
var myFunction= function () {
     x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    if (x < 10) 
{
    text = x + "Success";
}
    else 
{
    text = (x + "Fail");
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: put your code in the answer itself. People shouldn't have to go off site to see it. Answers should be self contained

Comment: ooh really where did you get this rule from ? and why you down voted me ?? all stackoverflow users put jsfiddle and  codepen pages here !!!

Comment: Thanks so much this actually really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are couple of mistakes in your code

all the code must written in your function myFunction(); since the scope of x would be within that function only.

you can easily achieve this via jquery please have a look at below code and js fiddle demo

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#btnRoll').on('click',function(){
             var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
           var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);       
           if(x<10)
             $('#demo').html(x+' fail');
           else
             $('#demo').html(x+' Success');
        });
    });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5f97pz9/)

thanks